# copying .net core app from linux to windows error

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I designed .Net Core app using vs code on ubuntu machine and its working , I decided to move it from ubuntu to windows and run it through visual studio 2017 but its giving me this error:

```
cs5555: could not find 'Program' specified for main method
```

what could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my visual studio isn't updated to the last version of .Net core. So when I copied the code from Linux (last version of .Net core) to windows (.Net core outdated version) the app couldn't run.
**Just update Visual Studio add all issues should be fixed.**

Answer (score 1):

Have you renamed the class "Program"? 
Go to your console project, right click on it, Properties -> Application -> Startup object and choose your namespace from there.